# How do i make a composite generator that would output the same way as the prime generator with it?

Tags: java, for-loop, netbeans, generator, composite

I have been trying to impelement a Composite generator to work along side the prime number generator but I can't seem to figure out how to work it in. Every time I apply another section to the code under `if (isPrime) { count++;`, I get a else without if statment then the whole program stops working. Any suggestion to my problem?

```
package primegenerator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeGenerator{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    double user;`enter code here`
    System.out.print( " Enter any number: " );
    user = input.nextDouble();
    //Saving user's input for generator
    final int NUMBER_OF_PRIMES_PER_LINE = 10; //Display 10 per line
    int count = 0;
    int number = 2;

    System.out.println("Your Prime numbers are: \n");

    //Reapeatedly find prime numbers
    while (count < user) {
        //Assume the number is prime
        boolean isPrime = true; // Is the current number prime?

        //Test whether number is prime
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number / 2; divisor++) {
            if (number % divisor == 0) { //If true, number is not prime
                isPrime = false; //Set isPrime to false
                break; //Exit the for loop
            }
        }

        //Display the Prime number and increase the count
        if (isPrime) {
            count++; // Increase the count

            if (count % NUMBER_OF_PRIMES_PER_LINE == 0) {
                //Display the number and advance to the new line
                System.out.println(number);
            //Displays all primes by 10 a line
            }
            else
                System.out.print(number + " ");

            }
            //Check if the next number is prime
            number++;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* repeat the code from `System.out.println("Your Prime numbers are: \n");` to the end of your while loop, but change your `if(isPrime)` to `if(!isPrime)`

*The reason I don't advise that is because you are then looping through all the numbers twice and duplicating a lot of code that should really be in their own methods.*

If you know how to use a List() you could add all the prime numbers to one list and all the composite numbers to another after testing if the number is prime or not. Then worry about looping through the lists to display the numbers of each.

*The drawback of this approach is the possible massive memory usage if the number the user inputs is really large.*

If it doesn't matter whether you display the composites or primes first I would do a combination of the two like the following.

```
//Get user number
while (count < user)
{
    if (!isPrime(count)) //isPrime should be another method similar to your for loop which returns either true or false.
    {
        //Print the number, it is composite.
    }
    else
    {
        //save the number to a List of primes
    }
}

//Print out all the primes saved in the List
```

Comment: I have it generating all the prime numbers when you ask it to but i cant figure the code i need to use to allow the program to generate composites as well as primes but in a different list.